# How to re-register or override a grunt task?

Tags: gruntjs

I want to do something a little different than a grunt plugin we are using. How can I re-register a task?

I apologize if this is obvious or impossible. I've done quite a bit of searching on Google and SO, but I couldn't find anything.

I also tried using renameTask, but it says the package doesn't exist yet. I seem to have a misunderstanding of how grunt task registration works.

**Update on specific use case**

Specifically we want to extend the [grunt-maven-tasks](https://github.com/smh/grunt-maven-tasks) release task. At the current time we are unable to provide a pull request to update the project, so we were hoping we could override it from our grunt build.

Comment: Can't you simply not load the task you want to re-define ?

Comment: Maybe I can, but it didn't seem to be working. I tried doing a `grunt.registerTask('task:name', function(...`. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: No, That is the way to register a task. Which task are you trying to override ? In which plugin is it initially defined ?

Comment: @Eria I'll make an update